# Call a string from Java code to C code in android studio

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, gstreamer

The app on which I'm working on uses Gstreamer to communicate between an android device and a raspberry Pi.

I want the user to be able to set the IP address of the PI and not make it fixed as I have it now.

Meanwhile, I'm using the jstring Piip in the C code to assign the IP as follows:

```
 jstring Piip = "192.168.0.202";

 g_object_set(G_OBJECT(data ->videoudpsink), "host", Piip , NULL);
```

I need a way to be able to use a string from the java code in the C code to assign this Piip.

Comment: Take a look at this https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/

Comment: The value of a `jstring` is an indirect reference to a `java.lang.String` instance. Assigning a `char*` to a `jstring` is incorrect. You need to use the `NewString` or `NewStringUTF` functions that are part of the `JNIEnv`.